# How do I re-authenticate a user on Dropbox Core API? (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, dropbox, dropbox-api

My App used to work fine and upload without any issues, but now I'll get Error 401 and the solution seems to be re-authenticating according to the documentation. The thing is, I do not know if that refers to something I can do on the Dropbox Developer Console or if it's something that I must do on my App.

Comment: guess you need to download the new api... it worked for my app ;)

Comment: Do it in the app. Logout (unlink) and log back in. This gives your app a new auth token.

Comment: @Calleth'Zion' Done, but still the same.

Comment: @rmaddy I tried it using the following: 
    [[DBSession sharedSession] unlinkAll];
Does it make any difference where I place the unlink command?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS Dropbox SDK - Cannot upload or get metadata](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325875/ios-dropbox-sdk-cannot-upload-or-get-metadata)